# How can I use camera on android tv emulator (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-emulator, android-camera

I am making android tv app and I want to use labtop camera instead tv web cam for this app. but I can't use it. I tried to allow camera permission. How to use camera on tv emulator?

- I already checked verify configuration when I added avd.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEA9n.png
- Add my tv emulator config.ini
  [image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Try to select a camera(Webcam*) from the Dropdown Menu(Camera section) as I did on the screenshot

[image: Camera selection]

Comment: I tried select but it doesn't have options

Comment: In this case, please check camera settings in your system. If it is correctly configured, it should appear in the Dropdown Menu list

Comment: Android phone device can select camera setting but not tv device on my laptop. I think it's difference from phone.

Comment: You can try to set it manually `hw.camera.back = webcam0` or `hw.camera.front = webcam0` in the `~/.android/avd/emulator_name.avd/config.ini` file and check if it helps

Comment: Thank you I did. but it can't use webcam even I fixed config.ini. It shows message "Cold boot : different AVD configuration". And I can't use camera still. I added my config.ini.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nWL0.png